# YadisException on google authentication with openid4java

Tags: java, openid

I'm new to java and trying to use openid4java for authentication. For some openid providers it works well (for example with yandex) but it fails with another (for example with google). When I'm trying to login I get:

```
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x706: GET failed on
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/rystsov.denis : 404:HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

at the method

```
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation
```

I suppose this error is related with ssl, but I doubt about it. What should I do to avoid this exception?

I use tomcat6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong discovery URL; the correct URL for Google OpenID server discovery is

`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`

**DO NOT** replace `id` with username. User-specific OpenID URLs will be assigned automatically (and will not related to GMail username)